# what is the difference between the two format in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given these two snippets:

```
$.ready(function()
{
     ……
}
```

and

```
(function($){
  $(function(){

    ……

  });
})(jQuery);
```

It seems I use the first format but it does not work, so I would like to know what is the difference between them?

Also, is there a difference between putting the `<script src="" />` at the bottom of the page and the `head`?

Comment: I personally find it easier to use `jQuery(function($) { ... });` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference, among others things, is that those two are different functions:

- [`jQuery.ready`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.0.3/src/core.js#L362) is an **internal** method to trigger the ready event. It does not expect a function as argument, but a boolean.
- `$(function)` is a a shortcut for [`jQuery.fn.ready`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.0.3/src/core.js#L220), which is an **API method** to bind ready event handlers, i.e. functions that should be run when the DOM is loaded.

So, the first one "doesn't work" because it simply does not do what you think it does. I recommend to read the [`.ready` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

The fact that the second is wrapped in an [*immediately invoked function expression*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IIFE) has no impact on the functionality.

> Also, is there a difference between putting the `<script src="" />` at the bottom of the page and the head?

Assuming you are talking about binding handlers to the ready event, then no, there is no difference regarding execution.

---

For those who don't want to follow links:

`jQuery.ready`:

```
// Handle when the DOM is ready
ready: function( wait ) {

    // Abort if there are pending holds or we're already ready
    if ( wait === true ? --jQuery.readyWait : jQuery.isReady ) {
        return;
    }

    // Remember that the DOM is ready
    jQuery.isReady = true;

    // If a normal DOM Ready event fired, decrement, and wait if need be
    if ( wait !== true && --jQuery.readyWait > 0 ) {
        return;
    }

    // If there are functions bound, to execute
    readyList.resolveWith( document, [ jQuery ] );

    // Trigger any bound ready events
    if ( jQuery.fn.trigger ) {
        jQuery( document ).trigger("ready").off("ready");
    }
},
```

`jQuery.fn.ready`:

```
ready: function( fn ) {  
    // Add the callback
    jQuery.ready.promise().done( fn );

    return this;
},
```

Comment: Putting scripts in the head does have an effect on loading behaviour (time) as opposed to having them at the end of `<body>`.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between the two is that the first assumes `jQuery` is set to the variable `$`.  The second does not.

The second defines `$` in a sandbox, as a parameter to a function, and then passes `jQuery` in for that parameter.  It's a common way of using the shorthand `$` even while in [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) mode.

```
(function($){  // <----- $ is defined ONLY within THIS function
  $(function(){
    ……
  });
})(jQuery);    // <------- jQuery being passed in for $
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your last question:

Putting javascript at the bottom of a page ensures that the page's HTML is loaded before execution. Including a javascript file at the bottom of the page puts its order of loading last behind all other files, as far as I am aware.

The snippets you have provided should be identical in execution, though using the first is more appropriate. The second feels... Redundant.

Comment: The snippets are not identical. The first one calls `jQuery.ready`, the second calls `jQuery.fn.ready`.